# How can I take a screenshot of the GRUB menu?

Tags: windows, grub, screenshot

How can I take a screenshot like this?

[image]

I tried pressing <kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd>, and then trying to paste it in MS Paint after booting to Vista, but it did not work.

Comment: `Print Screen` will never work because a "clipboard" is an OS-level feature (and even higher level - X11 - on Linux).

Comment: the iPhone 5 has a great camera

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a Linux virtual machine with VirtualBox, VMware, etc. and screen capture it from your host operating system.

Comment: yes, I thought of that. Actually the OS is already installed (not on a virtual machine), and I needed to post screenshots at [this question](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/4026/need-help-booting-the-machine-using-the-ubuntu-10-04-installer-cd).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there isn't any hardware-level clipboard and likely never will be ;( but VMs have it good in terms of cross-OS clipboards.  (I always consider it cheating xD)

Answer (score 3):

1. Load Linux in  **Virtual Machine in Windows**
2. At GRUB Menu
3. Print Screen Button
4. Paste it in MS Paint
5. Save File